# Angular 2 weird template scope behavior

Tags: scope, typescript, angular

Just went through the [Tour of Heroes tutorial app](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) and experienced some interesting behavior within my template. I started the second part of the tutorial with the following code:

```
class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <div><input [(ng-model)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"></div>
    </div>
    `,
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

class AppComponent {
  public title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  public hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };
}
```

When instructed to add the array of new heroes (`var HEROES: Hero[] = [ /* Hero Data */];`) and the new property to my component, I assumed we were replacing the original `hero` property and ended up with this:

```
class AppComponent {
  public title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  public heroes = HEROES;
}
```

Next, the template was modified like so:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ng-for="#hero of heroes">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
<div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div>
  <label>name: </label>
  <div><input [(ng-model)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"></div>
</div>
```

In the browser, the unordered list then rendered one `li` per `hero` in the array, but did not print the `name` or `id`. Crazy. After some tinkering, I realized that if I added the original `hero` property back to the `AppComponent` class all of the heroes in the array rendered just fine. Also, if I simply removed any template code referencing the `hero` property *not* in the `ng-for` loop the list would also render just fine.

Here is what I expected:

1. In my original version, all of the heroes in the array should be reflected in the unordered list, but then all of the hero values outside of the loop should be undefined or possibly the last item in the list.
2. When I added back the original hero property, there should be some sort of name collision or some other side effect.

How does this work the way it does?

Edit: Here is the requested plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/U3bSCaIOOjFdtw9XxvdR?p=preview

Comment: Can you add a plunker of your exact code. I couldn;t reproduce your issue

Comment: I added a plunker. Simply toggle the comment on the hero property to see the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so with your plunker I got a bit more of what you were trying to do and the issues you were having.

My Working plunk with more details is [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/ajY0CI?p=preview)

**1. NG-For**

When you do a NG-For loop the "#" variable is isolated to be inside the loop only. I renamed it "domhero" so you can see.

You had a few calls to it OUTSIDE of the li object which wouldn't work. I re-wrote it a bit to put all your titles and stuff inside the LI loop.

**2. Variables from the object**

On the input you were trying to access a variable from inside the ng-for loop which you cant do. Once you close out of a loop you cant access those variables. So I showed where I was binding to, to make it clearer for you.

I think it got confusing when you had so many things named the same thing all over the place (hero, heroes, HEROES, class: hero) if you take a look at the plunker I made I renamed the variables to help mark where they are coming from.

Hope it helps!

```
p
```

Comment: I added a plunker. Simply toggle the comment on the hero property to see the results.

Comment: I've edited my answer with more details and a link to a revised version of your plunker

Comment: I had no problems getting the example to work so I know what I need to do in order to make that happen. I am more curious as to why when I had errors in the template before this point, the app would just say "loading..." and I know that accessing the "#" variable outside the loop shouldn't work but I want to know why this particular error caused this strange behavior of empty bullets instead of just showing "loading..."

Comment: It said loading because if you look at index.html that is what is between the <my-app></my-app> tags. The bullets are because you had them inside a LI so it looped and showed bullets but there was nothing between the <li></li> so no content was loaded.

Comment: I understand that, I just mean when something is wrong it causes an error and no render happens so it said "loading" forever. I expect that same behavior instead of the bullets when I have the out of scope hero, not what I got. Perhaps this question just isn't a good fit for SO.

Comment: It all depends at what level the error happens. For example if you have bad code in a different view, the page will often load fine. Then when you navigate to it it will throw the errors. Some errors too aren't blocking of the renderer, so everything else is fine but you call a null reference or something and it only effects that one component. Generally, If I do something that gets stuck on "Loading" I know its a bigger error..

Comment: That makes sense enough.